# can not see base64 image

Tags: html, css, svg, base64

I convert my `svg` picture to `base64` and input as background image for button, when I download it using web-tools I can open it, so link is valid.

But I can not see it in browser.  Please help to resolve this problem.

Here is a link:

```css
 background-image: url("data:images/svg;base64, 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");
```

and all code in editor [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hp2mmh2/)

Comment: IT should start with `data:image/svg+xml;base64`. Please use this links like https://www.base64-image.de/  to auto generate images

Comment: Thanks for your help! it works now